# SASS/Compass will not build - exit code 255 (Sublime Text 3)

Tags: sass, compass-sass, sublimetext3

I am trying to add sass/scss to an existing project. I have no problems getting it to build in one of my other projects but in this particular one I get the following error:

```
\abcheating.co.uk\abc\sass' was unexpected at this time.
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 255]
[cmd: build.cmd "C:\Users\Marc\Dropbox\Clients - Shared Folders\Websites (1)\abcheating.co.uk\abc\sass" "C:\Users\Marc\Dropbox\Clients - Shared Folders\Websites (1)\abcheating.co.uk\abc"]
[dir: C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Compass]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\database;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\PHP\ext;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\PHP;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Smart Projects\IsoBuster;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Ruby193\bin]
```

I would really appreciate some help getting to the bottom of this, does anyone recognise this error or know what it means?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you run `build.cmd "C:\Users\Marc\Dropbox\Clients - Shared Folders\Websites (1)\abcheating.co.uk\abc\sass" "C:\Users\Marc\Dropbox\Clients - Shared Folders\Websites (1)\abcheating.co.uk\abc"` from the command line?

Comment: Any news as to what causes this error? I'm currently facing the same issue and there is not much info online.

Comment: This was almost a year ago now, but as memory serves I fixed it by doing 2 things....1. It didn't like the brackets in the path so I removed those....2. I added something to the PATH environment variable for windows and that seemed to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have special chars like brackets or braces in your path. Move your project to a more generic path without those special chars and it should work as usual.

**Good**

```
C:\mypath\projects\my_project
```

**Bad**

```
C:\mypath\projects\my_project (1)\mysuperwebsite
```

Head over to Github for first-level support. Thanks. :)

https://github.com/whatwedo/Sublime-Text-2-Compass-Build-System/issues/59

Comment: It might also help to check the PATH environment variable is set up correctly if the problem persists